# How to trace errors in inittab?

Tags: init, sco-unix

My OS ( SCO Unix ) loads the kernel, but no more. I can't enter even the single user mode. There is no errors on screen. I can load my emergency CD, and mount the FS. How can I trace if there is some errors in inittab?